# How can I make a custom traineddata with data from langdata in Tesseract

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm coding a program to take words(in my case russian and french words) from a vocabulary list and then to put them automatically on a flashcard website.

I'm using Tesseract for the OCR, precisely PyTesseract, but first I'm testing tesseract for better knowledge.

I saw that tesseract make the mistakes of turning russian vowels with accents(ò,à,...)(used for educational purposes most of the time) into other russian letters, and saw that someone, [with the same problem](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata/pull/12), had created trained data(if i understood correctly) for [russian with accents](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata/tree/main/rus_accent)

The problem is, i can not find a way to make it a traineddata file, to test it and later use it in my code. I found the [tesstrain](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesstrain) git, but was not able to make it work with the data found.

I honestly don't know if I am missing something, not understanding correctly something, or if we simply don't train data with these types of files anymore.

If you got any clue, that would help me a lot.

Good night!